# How to display styles in wordpress admin post page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have some specific styles for my clients website. For example, all the links are one color and I also have special fonts for different headings. How can I make these styles also apply when creating a post in the admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook to enqueue your styles:

```
function enqueue_my_admin_style()
{
  wp_enqueue_style( 'yourstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/yourstyle.css', false, '1.0', 'all');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_admin_style');
```

You will have to make sure your CSS selectors work for both admin and the regular view.